# Should boolean logic be done earliest?

Tags: java, boolean-logic

I have two ways to code the append function, which appends two arrays depending on the boolean. Below are two coding paradigms which although sound opinionated, I am pretty sure one of them would offer more advantages. Should the boolean logic be placed in append or should it be done as soon as possible in the code?

option 1

```
append(foo1, foo2, boolean) {
   if (boolean) {
      foo1.append(foo2);
   } else {
      foo2.append(foo1);
   } 
}

function (boolean){
   append(foo1, foo2, boolean);
}
```

or - option 2

```
append(foo1, foo2) {
   foo1.append(foo2);
}

function (boolean){
   if (boolean) {
       append(foo1, foo2);
   }  else {
       append(foo2, foo1);
   } 
}
```

Comment: You're really nitpicking at this point. You'll possibly save some memory by not passing a 3rd parameter in to the function, but processing will be essentially the same. It's really not worth spending time trying to decide which is "better".

Comment: I would say simpler is better. The order of parameters is implied by append, so switching is adding a source of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends

If you always want to supply a boolean value to your append function I would go with the first one.

But normally I would suggest the second option because it implements a "generic" append-function.

Comment: I wouldn't implement a function which only serves to wrap a native (String) method; I don't see the value-added there. But in terms of the two choices, above, they look equivalent in most respects - not sure what he's trying to optimize - performance, clarity/maintainability, reusability, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take advantage of overloading?

```
// Used when ordering is unknown or generic append foo2 to foo1 
append(foo1, foo2) {
   foo1.append(foo2);
}


// Used when order is known
append(foo1, foo2, boolean) {
   if (boolean) {
      foo1.append(foo2);
   } else {
      foo2.append(foo1);
   } 
}
```

This way you can get the flexibility of a generic function and the precision, given a situation you know the appending order.

Answer (score 0):

Second approch is more generic and clean. Append should perform append operation on given inputs. Checks can go before append call.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option two, and then simply remove the custom append function which only serves to wrap the native String.append method - i.e. there is no reason for it. Thus you only need a single function/method:

```
// no need to write an append function which does what String.append already does...
function (boolean) 
{
  if (boolean) {
    foo1.append(foo2);
  } else {
    foo2.append(foo1);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, ask yourself if it is really necessary to create a new `append()` method that accepts two `Foo` instances. For me, the API is more simple by calling the `append()` method associated with `Foo` class. Compare usage below:

**Example 1**

```
foo1.append(foo2); 

// alternatively
foo2.append(foo1);
```

**Example 2**

```
append(foo1, foo2); 

// alternatively
append(true); 

// or 
append(foo1, foo2, true);
```

In the first examples the intention of which object is appended to which is clear. In the second example, you must either document the method or you must look at the implementation to find out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with option 2, because it's a cleaner and more intuitive implementation.

We should try to design a function's signature (name + parameters) in a way that it is self-explanatory and clearly indicates what it does. One principle we should follow to achieve such clarity is to make a function **DO JUST ONE THING**. That is: if the function returns a value without any side effect, make the returned value **single purpose**. If there is any side effect, make it **one side effect only**.

Based on the reasoning above, option 2 is a clear winner. `append(A, B)` has a single side effect, and can be reused in a much wider context. `append(boolean)` requires the caller to decide just one thing: the appending order.